# Custom table of contents with appendices, how to get 'Chapter' and 'Appendix'

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, titletoc

I try to generate a table of contents which hopefully should look something like

> **Chapter 1** First chapter ....
>
> **Chapter 2** Second chapter ....
>
> **Appendix A** First appendix ....
>
> **Appendix B** Second appendix ....

So far I have tried the following,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\titlecontents{chapter}%
 [0em]% 
 {\addvspace{2em}}%
 {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% 
 {\hspace{-0em}}% 
 {\hfill\contentspage}% 
 [\addvspace{0pt}]% 

\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[4]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{Third subsection}\lipsum[7]
%appendices 
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}\lipsum[1]
\section{Some section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Second appendix}\lipsum[5]
\section{Some section}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[7]
\end{appendices}
%
\end{document}
```

But this seems to give the output

[image: Table of contents]

So, it is clear that there have to be something like `if 'appendix', write Appendix`, but I do not know how to put this into LaTeX logic. However it seems to be even more problems to my approach. Do anyone know how to solve this? Or have tricks how to create nice looking table of contents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the arguments of `\titlecontents`, replace `\chaptername` with `\@chapapp`. Also, at the beginning of the `appendices` environment a changed definition of `\@chapapp` (to `\appendixname`)  must be forwarded to the `.toc` file. Last, but not least, remove the `titletoc` option from the `appendix` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter

\titlecontents{chapter}%
 [0em]% 
 {\addvspace{2em}}%
 {\bfseries\@chapapp\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% 
 {\hspace{-0em}}% 
 {\hfill\contentspage}% 
 [\addvspace{0pt}]% 

\g@addto@macro\appendices{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\@chapapp}{\appendixname}}%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[4]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{Third subsection}\lipsum[7]
%appendices 
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}\lipsum[1]
\section{Some section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Second appendix}\lipsum[5]
\section{Some section}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{Some subsection}\lipsum[7]
\end{appendices}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I aimed for, sorry for the confusion with the `titletoc` option

Comment: @nunatak That was indeed the hardest part. ;-)

Comment: +1 It works substituting `\@chapapp` with `\chaptername`, too.

Comment: @karlkoeller True, but I prefer the more general (though, sadly, internal) macro.

Comment: @lockstep but what is actually the difference, why is `\@chapapp` a note general notion than substituting with `\chaptername`?

Comment: @nunatak `\@chapapp` is defined as `\chaptername` outside the appendix and as `\appendixname` within the appendix.